# Problem with substring a String and display it to textView

Tags: android

i have this code that warks perfectly

```
 UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() { //Defining a Callback which triggers whenever data is read.
    @Override
    public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
        String data = null;

        try {
            data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tvAppend(textView, data);
    }
};
```

I'm trying to substring the string data and display it to textView but my app crashes. I don't know why. Its about encoding of data string?

Comment: And, what is tv?
Where do you do the substring? Is that function not logging anything?

Comment: Can you post the error message here?

Comment: the problem is not at the first block of code but in the second when im trying to substring the String data then my app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a case when the byte[] to String conversion fails.

I would suggest you replace

```
  String data = null;
```

to

```
  String data = "";
```

Also add the crash log.